# How do you read the differential mark aloud?

Tags: mathematics, symbols, reading-aloud

[image: a mathematical expression with differentials in it]

How do you read the differential mark?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Formally, **The derivative of**...

In full:

Y equals the sine of f-of-x, implies that the derivative of y equals cos f-of-x times the derivative of f of x.

Informally, and depending on dialect, you can say either 'prime' ([as per Humbulani's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/43016/5446)) or 'dash' -  f prime of x, y-dash etc. The former is predominant in (but is not restricted to) the US, while the latter is relatively common in the wider Anglosphere.

Refer to: [How do you pronounce the symbol ' in f'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47339/how-do-you-pronounce-the-symbol-in-f) and [What is the practical difference between a differential and a derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23902/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-a-differential-and-a-derivative) for further information.

Comment: I also have a math degree and have never heard 'dash' as a term for differentiation.

Comment: @Hellion it's not a term for differentiation per se, merely an ***informal*** description of the notation (seemingly rather localised!)

Comment: As I've said in my deleted post, I am currently dealing with mathematical stuff and watching lectures. I am 100 % sure  that nobody among mathematicians says 'dash' in speech in the context of math.

Comment: @bruisedreed,  A *dash* is a horizontal stroke near the midline of letters, like `-`.  the `'` character is quite simply not a dash at all; it would be referred to as *quote* or *apostrophe*.

Comment: @Humbulani: I am a professional mathematician and I have personally heard other professional mathematicians say "dash" in this context.  I am trying to remember who it was and what dialect of English they spoke.  Probably British English - it definitely wasn't American English.

Comment: A simple test to check whether *dash* is in use is to google for `"f double dash"`. Among other links (which seem to come from all over the world: UK, NZ, FI, IN, BE, GR, AU, etc.; I can't tell much about US but I can see a lot of .com and .net links) is one from Math.SE stack: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47339/how-do-you-pronounce-the-symbol-in-f.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge What do you call this mark? I am reading textbooks written by American authors. The same applies to lectures I am watching. American lecturers and instructors in mathematics say 'prime'. I know nothing about spelling in British English.

Comment: @Humbulani: I personally call it "prime"; I am a native American English speaker and I would agree that "prime" is the correct term in *American* (mathematical) English.  But there are lots of other dialects - as I said, I have definitely heard "dash" although I am not sure which dialect to associate it with.  In any case, I would certainly not advise you to draw conclusions about what "nobody among mathematicians says" without broader experience!

Comment: After reading the conversation between @Humbulani and Nate, I think it's safe to conclude that _prime_ is common, and _dash_ is rare but worth mentioning – and that there's usually more than one way to translate a mathematical expression into English.

Comment: At a Cambridge University (where I studied mathematics) "dash" was more common than "prime". (Cambridge University is in the United Kingdom)

Comment: @J.R. It's not rare, it's dialectal.  Or to put it another way, it's rare in some places but common in others.

Comment: Dash is common in Australia; prime is understood but rare.

Comment: Here in India, `dash` is far more common than `prime`.

Answer (score 10):

> **f′(x)**

is read

- f prime of x, or
- the derivative of f of x, or
- the derivative of f with respect to x.

> **f″(x)**

is read

- f double prime of x, or
- the second derivative of f of x, or
- the second derivative of f with respect to x.

> **ẋ**

is read

- x dot, or
- the derivative of x with respect to time, or
- the time derivative of x.

If *x* is a distance, ẋ can also be read as *the x component of the velocity*.

If *x* is a distance, and is also the only direction of motion, ẋ can also be read as *speed* or *velocity*.

> **ẍ**

is read

- x double dot, or
- the second derivative of x with respect to time.

If *x* is a distance, ẍ can also be read as *the x component of the acceleration*.  If *x* is a distance, and is also the only direction of motion, ẍ can also be read as *acceleration*.

Answer (score 9):

This mark means the first derivative of f. You can also call it a derivative of f. It is definitely wrong to call it the differential mark. American mathematicians read it as 'prime'. For example, f' (x) - f prime of x.

Comment: In British English that is how I have heard it pronounced as well.

Answer (score 1):

In high school and junior-high school in Japan, the symbol x' is usually pronounced as "x dash". However, in universities it is also read as "x prime". I think teachers in university are strongly influenced by Americans. I read it in both ways in a university.