# Does single quote (') pronounce "dash" , "prime" or something else?

Tags: reading-aloud

[The lecturer is saying](https://youtu.be/_9RGpiWjn_o?t=207)

> we write as f `dash` of x

when talk about this formula.

[image]

I heard someone pronounce it as "prime" somewhere else.

Does single quote (') pronounce *dash*, *prime* or something else?

Comment: Another related question:  [How do you read the differential mark aloud?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An apostrophe is pronounced as "prime" in the context of calculus. The formula you mentioned would be pronounced as "f prime of x".

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but the lecturer seems like a reliable source of acceptable English. The duplicate post reports that "dash" is used in this context in some English-speaking regions.